# Could not save Data in Core-Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I am new to Core-Data so please help me with this.
i have this exception

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'ModelForProfile' in this model.'
```

Although i searched almost all the answers available on internet and browsed the links available on stack but nothing seems to be understanding to me.

I have A few(5-7) different view's and a save button on each view.
1.) I am using Core-Data To save Data.MI doing right thing ??
2.) I need to have different Models for each View ??
3.) Initially i had an exception and when i browsed the web came to know that i need to change following method a bit

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"saveButtonForBasicInfo" withExtension:@"momd"];
    //NSURL *modelURL1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"saveButtonForProfile" withExtension:@"momd"];

    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
  //  __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL1];

    return __managedObjectModel;
}
```

Where " saveButtonForBasicInfo " is xcDataModel for the first model(First View).

and it worked perfect. But when this error occurred I tried adding a couple to more lines.
If you could see the commented lines.

Please Help me with this. As I am a bit confused .

**Thank You,**

**Best Regards.**

Comment: Find the code have entityName and change it match entity name in your model. Your Error say about that

Comment: i did that..infact i deleted the entity created a new one..but no change..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some basic concepts:

You typically only have **one** NSManagedObjectModel in your app. It describes your entities (something like objects) and their attributes (something like properties).

This model is initialized at app launch, you should not have to revisit it. This usually happens in the AppDelegate setting up the "Core Data Stack" which also includes the NSManagedObjectContext and the NSManagedObjectStoreCoordinator.

Each of your views should use the NSManagedObjectContext to access the model and its data. Your suggestion that you need different models for different views is way off.

You should name your various things in a meaningful way. "saveButtonForBasicInfo" is not a meaningful name for a model. Call it something like "Widgets".

Similarly an entity should be something like "User", "Appointment", "Project", "Location", "Class", etc., i.e. something that represents something real. "ModelForProfile" is a very unsuitable entity name.

Comment: So will it work only if i change the names to appropriate one's.
And as you said i have only one ManagedObject so do i need to have another one if yes how do i do that ??
Thank YOU !!!

Comment: No, it will also work with bad names, but nobody, including you, will be able to understand the code. And no, you only need one model, as explained above. Please read my answer and make sure you understand it.

Comment: Mundi : OHKAY !!! Let me change it a bit...and i will accept your answer.
Thank You.